# General Database Question - Indexed ID field Performance vs Limit (Top) Performance (Salesforce)

Tags: oracle, salesforce, soql

I am troubleshooting (or at least identifying) possible causes of poor query performance within our Saleforce org.   I suspect my question, however, will be applicable to most database engines.

We have fairly large volumes of data within our Salesforce org.  Our problematic objects have rouhgly 15M records.  We built an API on top of our org which pulls back data and we are really struggling with performance.    Please know, that we understand there are things that can be done in the long term, but my question is more about just understanding the underlying query engine for databases.

The issue is this:
We can run a query:

```
Select X From Account Where [IndexedField] Like 'value%' LIMIT 1000
```

for some reason, that query will outperform a query such as:

```
Select X From Account Where [Id] = 'IdValue'
```

both fields in the where clause are indexed, but for some reason, it takes a while for a single Id filter to return the result, where you might get the top X records faster.

Understanding that SFDC uses a hybrid EAV approach to their data, but their data is stored in an Oracle DB, I suspect this has to do with the generic way that Oracle performs their search.

Why might it take longer to find a single record by ID, than it would to find [X] records that meet a given criteria?   I have looked at the query plans, both have low costs and obviously the ID has the lowest cost.

Need to explain to our UI guys the impact of searching across 15M records to the best of my ability.

Comment: Can you activate the [10046 trace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sqltun.htm#sthref9790)? This is he best way to see if the problem is in the DBMS.

Comment: That's looks strange to me. When you say the first query is faster how do you measure it? is it from a gui tool look Toad or is it from sqlplus? how big is the difference? Some GUI tools show only first n records (like first 50). Also can you post the table structure with indexes on it and also the execution plans for both queries by code formatting and editing the original question.  Note that your two queries are looking somewhat different - the second filter is on **[Id]** and first filter is on **[IndexedField]** so that is **not** exactly same so are you comparing 2 diff. things?

Comment: I don't know Salesforce but I have some scars from other EAV implementations. So is ACCOUNT an actual table or is it a view overlying EAV structures?

Comment: The way Salesforce works is Account is both an actual table AND a view.  The standard fields are their own table, whereas the custom fields are a view layered over the EAV object configuration.

Measurements are really nothing more than the eyeball test using the saleforce  native query profiler (dev console).  We've seen ID based queries actually time out, which should never happen.   I think the askTom article listed below is excellent information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer could be a number of things. Are the table statistics up to date? What hardware is the database running on? Performance tuning of an Oracle database on an X7 Exadata machine will be different compared to one running on an old V2. The version of Oracle you're running also has an impact on this, as there differences in the optimizer. Different versions of Oracle can handle identical queries in different ways, even if they are on identical hardware.

> Why might it take longer to find a single record by ID, than it would
>   to find [X] records that meet a given criteria? I have looked at the
>   query plans, both have low costs and obviously the ID has the lowest
>   cost.

Three words: Full Table Scan. Does your query gathering a single ID require a full table scan? The explain plan will tell you. A query that requires a full table scan can take longer than a query that takes advantage of an index scan. However, the inverse can also be true depending on your environment. The first query that gathers a range of values is obviously utilizing an index. Why isn't the second query also using that indexed column? That is likely part of the equation.

Here is a great AskTom answer that touches on this subject and explains in detail how index scans work, albeit the question is from the opposite perspective of why index scans can be slower than full table scans.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=blocks-read-using-index-vs-full-table-scan

Comment: Thank you sir, that article is exactly what I wanted to know.  I wanted to know how a tablescan could ever be faster than a index search, because we are seeing that as well.  And that logic can be translated to multiple scenarios.
Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, and good luck with resolving the performance issues!